# wp_remote_get not getting called in while loop

Tags: php, wordpress, iteration

I'm trying to iterate over all of my posts and update and ID attribute via *wp_remote_get*. It doesn't seem like the request is actually being made. It's on localhost and I see nothing hitting my local server. Am I missing something about *wp_remote_get* being non-blocking or something like that? Here is my function:

```
function convert_to_postgres() {
        $args = array(
            'post_type'=>'post', //whatever post type you need to update
            'numberposts'=>-1
        );

        $all_posts = get_posts($args);

        foreach($all_posts as $post){
            echo get_the_title($post);
            echo "<br>";

            if( have_rows('article_hotels', $post->ID) ) {
                while ( have_rows('article_hotels', $post->ID) ) : the_row();
                    $legacy_id = get_sub_field('tripcraft_hotel_id')['id'];
                    $url = get_option('tripcraft_widgets_hotel_master_url') . "/wordpress/hotels/legacy_id/{$legacy_id}";
                    $response = wp_remote_get($url);
                    $api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
                    echo get_sub_field('hotel_name');
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "Legacy ID: " . $legacy_id;
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "New ID: " . $api_response;
                    echo "<br>";
                endwhile;
                echo "<br>";
            } else {
                echo "No hotels found";
                echo "<br>";
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "<a href='options-general.php?page=plugin_hotel_id'>Back</a>";
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it turns out, wordpress wasn't running locally it was running on a different server. Therefore, localhost was actually the server of the wordpress instance.